# C# class operator order

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a class for double arrays with simple +-*^/ operators. 
I have a problem with the power operator ^, I want it to be the highest priority (evaluated first) operator but it is actually the lowest. 
For example:

```
Vector v = new Vector(new double[] {2.0});
return v*v^2;
```

Returns a vector with the entry 16 instead of 8. 
Is there a way to control the operator priority in the class?

Comment: Simply wrap the second v in brackets, like: `v*(v^2)`. It wouldn't change the priority, however instead of first doing v*v and taking that result, it would evaluate v * ( the result of this operation )

Comment: Answer: v*(v^2)

Comment: There is no power operator in c#, it is your implementation of xor one. That's why you need to use parenthesis

Comment: How would you describe behavior of v^3.7? I can see ^2, but can't figure out what would be"simple" explanation for all other values.

Comment: {1,2,3}^3.7 = ??? Also I don't get how you computed 8...

Comment: I see. I was hoping there was a way of controlling operator order as there's a way of controlling the meaning of the operators. Say one wants to define a class with entirely different meanings to all operator symbols it would make sense to change the ordering as well. So just to be clear, is there no way to control the ordering?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov 2*2^2 is 8. What is computed is first multiplication and then exponentiation. So 4^2 gets the mathematically wrong answer of 16.

Comment: As explained in previous comments ^ is "xor" with low priority. I'm interested how you define powers of vectors... Especially if normally you get scalar as result of multiplying two vectors...

Comment: This is very unusual way to define multiplication of vectors... Good luck explaining that to people trying to read your code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov well that's the way I need it to be... and in my context it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) table, the bitwise-exclusive or operator is actually lower in the precedence than the multiplication.

You cannot change the order of precedence, but you can manipulate it by grouping them within `( )` blocks

So changing your assignment to:

```
return v*(v^2);
```

Would multiply `v` with the result of `v ^ 2`.

Comment: Is there a way around parenthesis? Maybe using a different symbol?

Comment: @AsaridBeck91 Not really no, you depend on the result of the operation of a single v, you would always have to single it out

Comment: @AsaridBeck91 note that `v*v^2` is simply `v*v*v`, you don't need power operator (although `^` is not power operator in c#, its XOR bitwise operator.)